# Nginx with software installed in subdirectories

Tags: nginx, directory

I'd like to create a directory/website structure like this:

```
/
/index.php
/tac
/tac/1app1/index.php
/tac/1app2/
/tac/1app3/
```

So there is one CMS in the root.
In subdirectories there should be other CMS/web apps.

How do I have to change the config to get the subdirectories working with different web apps?

```
server {
server_name domain.com;
root /var/www/domain.com;

access_log /var/log/nginx/domain.com_access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/domain.com_error.log;

location ~ \..*/.*\.php$ {
    return 403;
}
location ~ /\. {
    deny all;
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
}
location ~ ^/tac/(.+\.*)$ {
    alias /var/www/domain.com/tac/$1;
    try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;

    # try_files $uri;
    allow all;

    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 150;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}
location / {
    try_files $uri @rewrite;
}
location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^ /index.php;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 150;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}
}
```

Currently I receive this error: `FastCGI sent in stderr: "Access to the script '/var/www/domain.com/tac/1app1/index.php/s/dashboard' has been denied (see security.limit_extensions)" while reading response header from upstream`
and already changed `security.limit_extensions` to accept everything and the problem persists.
So I assume the issue comes from `index.php/s/dashboard` not being a valid extension or that file cannot be found (of course not, it's parameters that should be passed on to the index.php script but Nginx doesn't seem to do that?

Comment: What's the problem you're experiencing? What's inside the logs?

Comment: I added some more details.